# SDL struct Objects - Set to nullptr After Calling Destroy Function?

Tags: c++, sdl

Say I have an `SDL_Window` object, `SDL_Window *window`. Once I'm finished using it, I call `SDL_DestroyWindow(window)` to destroy it. Should I then say `window = nullptr` or does the destroy function take care of that? I have seen some code set it to `nullptr`, and other code not. Thanks.

Comment: if you are not in a managed environment or it is not a smartpointer, then setting it to nullptr has no effect, so you should set it to null only if you then in your code you are checking for null before you acccess soe fields like it. If you don't, you should not set it to null, as it is a line of code that you don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deallocate memory using `free()` or `delete` the pointer will keep its value. So I guess it's the same for `SDL_DestroyWindow()`.

Setting your pointer to `nullptr` won't be necessary since you are not supposed to use memory you just freed. But if you feel comfortable setting it to `nullptr` I won't stop you.